# Set parent with automatic weight for selected bones only

Tags: rigging, parent

[image]How can I easily set the the selected bones parent of the selected mesh?
Reading the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#bone-parent) it works well while setting the bone directly as parent but as soon as I use with automatic weight it use all the bones of my armature.

On my screen-shot if I do ctrl-p then automatic weight and move the hips, it will also deform the arm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the vertices in *Edit* mode, remove them from all vertex groups named like a bone, and add them to this one group that has the same name as the bone you want to parent the vertices to.

Blender creates a vertex group for each bone if you parent the armature *With Automatic Weights*, *With Empty Groups* or *With Envelope Weights*. The weight assigned to the vertices in the group controls the influence of the bone on the mesh.

If you move the hips and the arm moves as well then you need to remove the arm vertices from the hips vertex group. You can do this visually in *Weight Paint* mode (paint with WP=0), or in *Edit* mode with plain numbers by editing the values in the N-panel (Item > Vertex Weights) or assigning/removing vertices from the group (Object Properties > Vertex Groups).

If you remove the weight of the hip bone from the arm you should add it to the arm bone (keyword *normalize weights*).

Answer (score 2):

Blender does 4 things when you armature parent something:

1. It parents the mesh object to the armature object, just like any other parenting;
2. It creates an armature modifier on the mesh object, targeting the selected armature;
3. If parenting with empty groups or automatic weights, it creates a vertex group for every deforming bone in the armature, with the same name (any groups that already exist are unaffected);
4. If parenting with automatic weights, it fills those vertex groups from 3 with values determined by the automatic weights algorithm.

Understanding that, we can parent the mesh object to a subset of an armature:

1. Clean up the vertex groups on the object mesh.  Easiest is to just delete all of them; you don't want any populated vertex groups with the same names as deforming bones.
2. Duplicate the armature.  Enter edit on the duplicate.  Delete all bones but those you want to affect the mesh (keep your 3 arm bones, delete all others.)
3. Parent the mesh object to your duplicate with automatic weights.
4. Re-parent the mesh object to the *original* armature with armature deform or empty groups.
5. Delete the duplicate armature and delete the extra, now untargeted armature modifier on the mesh object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it helps me to understand how it works. And vertex group was the keyword I was missing. It's hard to chose "the" accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this question correctly, here is a handy [solution from panicq06](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/wgdbbc/?sorting=hot#comment-31534):

1. Select the mesh and then also the armature.
2. Parent with "Armature Deform".
3. Select your desired bones and then also the mesh (depending on your version, you may need to switch from Pose Mode to Object Mode before also selecting the mesh).
4. Go to "Weight Paint", then to "Weights" (in the header menu) and select "Assign Automatic From Bones".

It should now be rigged using only the selected bones.

[image]
Hope this helps any passersby! Peace and God bless!